# Is NSCalendar a GUI control?

Tags: cocoa, calendar

ALL,

(The Apple documentation will really benefit from the screenshots, but lacking that...)

Is NSCalendar a GUI control or just some helper class to work with different locales and there is another control I can use in my GUI program to display the calendar?

TIA!

Comment: See [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar). "NSCalendar objects encapsulate information about systems of reckoning time in which the beginning, length, and divisions of a year are defined. They provide information about the calendar and support for calendrical computations such as determining the range of a given calendrical unit and adding units to a given absolute time."

Answer (score -1):

**NSCalendar** is not a **GUI control**.
Apple has **no** calendar control, and many developers are lost in how to build one.
Check this url **https://iosexample.com/tag/calendars/**.
It will help you.

Comment: thank you. pretty weird they have a picker but not a calendar. I guess I will try to use NSDatePicker... BTW, I was looking for Objective-C one for desktop.

Comment: See [Date Pickers](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/selectors/date-pickers/).